# Re-Finding an Html Element on a Page (Over and over and over and over......)

Tags: html, dom, getelementbyid

I am visiting example.com, and programmatically finding certain HTML Elements that I want to "track" -- i.e., I revisit the page regularly to see if the elements' text changes.  The million dollar question is how can I maximize the likelihood that I will find the *right/same* HTML element each time I go back to the page? (I'm revisiting several times within the same day -- the site changing its format or layout is not a concern of mine).

Ex. If we're talking about the label within the div within the left div within the html body, then my comparison should always be with the same element on the page.

I've come up with some options, but all of them have faults:

1. I can create a DOM-Path, and work my way down from the html tag each time I go to the page.  BUT: Insert one element somewhere and it screws the whole thing up.
2. I can try to use some combination of IDs or classes to identify the element.  BUT 2 problems: A lot of these elements do not have ids or classes; and often times the
   classes or ids change along with the content.
3. I can try to use WebBrowser's GetElementFromPoint -- This may be my best bet, but does anybody know how accurate and reliable that is?

Any ideas of the best way to do this?  Anything I'm missing?  Has anyone ever done this kind of stuff before?  Perhaps a combination of several methods?

Comment: I guess you have to adjust your grabbing page code every time. There is no absolute approach in your case. I suggest to use #2 from your list.

Comment: Identification by ID of the wanted element would be the best, because it's likely that they do not remove that ID. But I guess you don't have an ID there. -- Parsing and XPaths are not useful at all with changes in the structure. -- What about jQuery selectors? This would be like _partial_ xpaths (find a specific class and specific children combination to check). -- But there's really no way you can be 100% sure here.

Comment: Imho: Don't try to scrape pages that don't want to be scraped. Look if there's an API available that you are allowed to use.